# Image keeps displaying on top of text

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to put an image in my LaTeX file using this method:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure 1.png}
\caption{....}
\label{Figure 1.}
\end{figure}
```

My document class is `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}`

The issue is that the image keeps displaying over the text when I want it to be on top of the page, and its width is equal to the text width.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: This is what happens when I use the above code]

Comment: as you show no example it is hard to guess your problem, if you mean you have 2 columns and this is over-printing the second column, replace `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` by `\begin{figure*}`

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure1.png}` with `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Figure1.png}`?

Comment: To provide us with code we can test, you can use `\includegraphics{example-image}`.

Comment: By way of clarification: You mean that the image is displaying just above the text, rather than overlapping it as a layer, yes?

Comment: @rallg I edited to include an example of what happens when I try to add the image, I want to have the image display on the same spot at the top of the page without overlapping with the text under it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried your solution but it still kept displaying on top of the text, I edited the post to show the issue.

Comment: no you would not get that from `figure*` naturally you get that from `figure` as you specify a single column figure with an image as wide as 2 columns

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh my god it worked! I changed to figure* only in begin but forgot to change the end hence why it was still showing the error. I fixed it and it worked! thank you!!